# How to change the Lotus Notes display name

Tags: lotus-notes

I wanted to change the Lotus notes email display name.

Email id is john.smith@example.com and Display name is 'John Smith'.

I wanted to change the display name as 'John S' without changing the email address.

I'm using Domino Release 9.0 (AIX/64)

Comment: Do you want to change the name displayed on outgoing emails sent to recipients outside of the internal Domino domain? Or do you want to change the internal Notes name?

Comment: You could change this notes name but leave their external email address the same. You'll have to add some specifics about what you are actually trying to do before you'll be able to get an answer.